# How to do exact and partial match on Lucene Text Field?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I have a requirement to do a exact and then partial match on field. 
Currently for same data, I am creating two fields one TextField (for partial match) and another StringField (for exact match). I have many fields like this where I need to apply similar logic.

Can you someone suggest a better approach then this?

Thanks,
Parth

Comment: Why not adding a checkbox "exact match" and using only a StringField with  a tokenizer to apply the matching type according that the checkbox is checked or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever an exact match is needed, just enclose your query in double quotes (") or use a [phrase query](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html) eventually setting a default slop (
Sets the number of other words permitted between words in query phrase). For a partial match,  a normal query will do.

Comment: Thanks AR1. I tried phrase query on TextField as suggested but its doing partial match. How to get exact match with phrase query ? Can you please post some code ?

Comment: @user3222372 - I believe there may be some confusion about exactly what "exact match" means to you.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest solution would be to use logical boolean query `(FieldName:test) or (FieldName:test*) or (FieldName:test~)` instead of creating multiple fields.

In this example we are trying to match three different cases:

1. Exact match
2. Partial match
3. Fuzzy search

Comment: sorry for the late response. Exact match (FieldName:test) would return all docs which has test in it. Exact match definition in my case is only that word is present in field.